# How to update JDK on Jenkins Server cartridge (OpenShift)?

Tags: jenkins, openshift, java

The Jenkins Server cartridge (OpenShift) uses OpenJDK 7u55.

How to update to OpenJDK 7u60 or 8u05 or Oracle JDK (7u60 or 8u05), please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using OpenShift's action hooks. Add a script which will check for the existence of the JDK you want to use, and download it if it doesn't exist.

For example, in `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy`, add this snippet:

```
#! /bin/bash
JDK_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0

if [[ ! -L $JDK_HOME && ! -d $JDK_HOME ]] 
  then 
  cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
  wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk8u20/archive/b17/binaries/jdk-8u20-ea-bin-b17-linux-x64-04_jun_2014.tar.gz
  tar xvf *.tar.gz 
  rm -f *.tar.gz
  ln -s jdk1.8.0_20 jdk1.8.0
fi
```

In Jenkins, you can then configure builds to use this JDK by configuring the PATH variable, in an "Execute Shell" action, like so:

```
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
```

This example retrieves 8u20. Sorry, I'm not sure of the links to use for the exact versions you mention. Also, word of warning, this download is over HTTP, without performing a check against the published [MD5 checksums](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/javase8-binaries-checksum-2133161.html). If you're doing anything serious, you should edit to code snippet to perform that check.