# OpenShift & Jenkins: Slave went offline during the build when using JDK 8

Tags: jenkins, build, openshift

I have an application in OpenShift that is built using Jenkins. The application is built using Gradle (configured according to https://blog.openshift.com/run-gradle-builds-on-openshift/) and needs to be built using JDK 8. I followed the advice from [How to update JDK on Jenkins Server cartridge (OpenShift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513572/how-to-update-jdk-on-jenkins-server-cartridge-openshift) and configured the JDK to be downloaded which works perfectly (I can see the JDK being downloaded in the log) however the build now never finishes, instead I get the following error:

> Slave went offline during the build
>   ERROR: Connection was broken: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
>       at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2332)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
>       at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:40)
>       at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
>       at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>   ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver aborted due to exception
>   hudson.AbortException: no workspace for diy-build #9
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:72)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
>   Finished: FAILURE

The build sometimes aborts at different stages, sometimes during the download of the dependencies, sometime sduring the compilation stage.

If I remove the JDK 8 from the build, it works again, however my tests fail because they need Java 8.

Comment: As the build aborts at different stages, have you tried checking whether the gear used as slave for the build has memory issues (https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues), perhaps accommodating the build on a larger gear?

Comment: I'm using the free version for now. I ended up using the preinstalled openjdk-8 in `/usr/lib/jvm/` which runs perfectly.

Comment: Cross ref; Timestamper plugin had a problem with this error. It was fixed  2013/Jun/04 11:05 AM, Released Timestamper 1.5.4 with this fix. See:  [JENKINS-17590] Builds fail because of "slave went offline during the build" - Jenkins JIRA ; ; https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17590